# ActionScript 3: Set the text of an animated Dynamic text instance

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, text, movieclip

I have a dynamic text field (textLabel) inside a Movie Clip (textMC). I am tring to set the text attribute like this:

```
textMC.textLabel.text = "this is my text";
```

This works fine, until I add key frames to textLabel.  I need to animate textLabel. But when it hits a keyframe, it changes back to the text I created on the stage.  How can I make the actionscript changes persistem over several keyframes?

Comment: After a day of working on this, I have given up and done the animation in ActionScript instead of the timeline.  *sigh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure in all the keyframes you textfield is named 'textLabel'. If in a frame it's called different then your code won't work.

Comment: Sorry, I was not descriptive enough.  I have added some detail.

Comment: I have decided to removed the timeline animation and I am now doing the animation in Actionscript.  Tedious, yes, but its working.